# XML searching python

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML of the next type:

```
<OUTPUT>
    <HEADER>

    </HEADER>
    <REGISTER>
        <RESULT>0</RESULT>
        <KEY1>CAR</KEY1>
        <KEY2>RED</KEY2>
        <KEY3>2013</KEY3>
        <ATTRIBUTE1>2000</ATTRIBUTE1>
        <ATTRIBUTE2>100000</ATTRIBUTE2>
    </REGISTER>
    <REGISTER>
        <RESULT>0</RESULT>
        <KEY1>TRUCK</KEY1>
        <KEY2>BLUE</KEY2>
        <KEY3>2014</KEY3>
        <ATTRIBUTE1>3000</ATTRIBUTE1>
        <ATTRIBUTE2>400000</ATTRIBUTE2>
    </REGISTER>
<OUTPUT>
```

How can I search the value of the ATTRIBUTE1 if the KEY1,KEY2, KEY3 have some values without looping in python? (some kind of lambda expression of c#)

I know thanks to @CommuSoft that I can use Xpath queries with libxml2. But when I try to install it using `pip install libxml2-python` I find the error

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement libxml2-python
```

Also I forgot to mention I'm using python 2.7 on anaconda and windows.

Comment: Lambda expressions? I would use an xpath query...

Comment: @CommuSoft could you give me an example with the  xml I gave? For example how search the ATTRIBUTE1 value if key1=TRUCK, KEY2=BLUE,KEY3=2014?

Comment: see answers (using xpath).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is better to process XML with a library, and in this case specifically with an [*XPath* query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python).

```
import libxml2

doc = libxml2.parseFile("tst.xml")
ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
res = ctxt.xpathEval("//REGISTER/ATTRIBUTE1[../KEY1/text()='TRUCK' and ../KEY2/text()='BLUE' and ../KEY3/text()='2014']")

doc.freeDoc()
ctxt.xpathFreeContext()
```

Here the query is:

```
//REGISTER/ATTRIBUTE1[../KEY1/text()='TRUCK' and ../KEY2/text()='BLUE' and ../KEY3/text()='2014']
```

The result is stored in `res`.

Comment: `libxml2-python` is a binding, did you install `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev` first?

Comment: I'm using windows (sudo is not for windows as far as I know) what command I have to execute?

Comment: @rlartiga: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520826/installing-libxml2-on-python-2-7-windows) help?

Comment: @rlartiga: can you update your question with the error you get with `pip`?

Comment: I deleted my comments and updated the answer, thanks

Comment: @rlartiga: can you install it with these [executables](http://users.skynet.be/sbi/libxml-python/).

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

Use [lxml with XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath).

```
import lxml.etree as etree

x = """<OUTPUT>
    <HEADER>

    </HEADER>
    <REGISTER>
        <RESULT>0</RESULT>
        <KEY1>CAR</KEY1>
        <KEY2>RED</KEY2>
        <KEY3>2013</KEY3>
        <ATTRIBUTE1>2000</ATTRIBUTE1>
        <ATTRIBUTE2>100000</ATTRIBUTE2>
    </REGISTER>
    <REGISTER>
        <RESULT>0</RESULT>
        <KEY1>TRUCK</KEY1>
        <KEY2>BLUE</KEY2>
        <KEY3>2014</KEY3>
        <ATTRIBUTE1>3000</ATTRIBUTE1>
        <ATTRIBUTE2>400000</ATTRIBUTE2>
    </REGISTER>
</OUTPUT>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(x)
xpath = "//REGISTER[./KEY1/text()='TRUCK' and ./KEY2/text()='BLUE' and ./KEY3/text()='2014']/ATTRIBUTE1"
for attribute1 in tree.xpath(xpath):
    print(attribute1.text)
```

Output:

```
3000
```

Comment: +1, but perhaps you can use the `/text()` for the conditions? Otherwise it's problematic if they have attributes as well...

Comment: `.text()` is not accepted by lxml XPath. This `./KEY3.text()='2014'` gives `XPathEvalError: Invalid expression` :(

Comment: It's not `.text()`, but `/text()` (with a slash).

Comment: @CommuSoft I'm trying this solution as well, there is a way to obtaining the value if I know there is one registry with that properties?

Comment: @rlartiga: I don't understand the question... gramatically it doesn't make much sense, please reformulate?

Comment: @Commusoft Ok he does a for because we can have more than a value or not? What if I know there is unique value

Comment: @rlartiga: I think there is an iterator version where you thus can break off the search after the first found match. But I'm not familiar with this library.